# Trying to get the ajax form submitted data in controller in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am  Trying to get the ajax form submitted data in the controller in laravel but getting nothing in controller request with the following code

ajax

```
$('.ace_text-input').keyup(function(e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/forksnippet/saveforksnippets',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(result) {
            $(".saveforksnippetbutton").attr("disabled", true);
            $(".saveforksnippetbutton ").html('Auto saving...');
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $(".saveforksnippetbutton ").html('Auto Saved');
        }
    });
});
```

Controller function

```
public static function saveforksnippets(Request $request)
{
   return $request->post('snippet_title');
}
```

Please help

Comment: try `return $request->all();` or `return $request->snippet_title;`

Comment: didn;t work @SalmanZafar

Comment: paste your routes file here

Comment: Route::post('/forksnippet/saveforksnippets','Forksnippet@saveforksnippets');

Comment: try remove `static` keyword from your `function`

Comment: it is working perfectly when I am trying to $("#form_snippets_form").submit(function(event) {

Comment: then may be there is an issue with your ajax code

Comment: Do you get any errors in your developer console?

Comment: I am trying to return the $request->post('snippet_title') but getting empty response @Dan

Comment: What does `dd($request->all())` output?

Comment: [object Object] nothing in that when I am returning  return $request->all();

Answer (score 0):

Add a key to your data object

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/forksnippet/saveforksnippets',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        payload: $(this).serialize(),
    },
    beforeSend: function(result) {
        $(".saveforksnippetbutton").attr("disabled", true);
        $(".saveforksnippetbutton ").html('Auto saving...');
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $(".saveforksnippetbutton ").html('Auto Saved');
    }
});
```

[Parse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) the serialized data in the controller

```
public function saveforksnippets(Request $request)
{
    parse_str($request->payload, $output);
    return $output['snippet_title'];
}
```

PS: I have removed the static scope of the function.